# How to change a position of an active item in Slick JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I've got a problem with Slick JS. I gotta center an active item as the second in a row, but it's automatically centralised as the third in a row.[image]

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.slider-for').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: true,
    fade: true,
    asNavFor: '.slider-nav',
    centerMode: true,

    responsive: [{
      breakpoint: 800,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
      },
    }, ]
  });
  $('.slider-nav').slick({
    slidesToShow: 4,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    asNavFor: '.slider-for',
    dots: false,
    arrows: false,
    centerMode: true,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    variableWidth: false,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 5000,
    speed: 1000,
    
    responsive: [{
      breakpoint: 800,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
      },
    }, ]
  });
})
```

I tried many times to find any solution in the Internet, but all my tries have failed

```js
$('.slider-for').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false,
  // fade: true,
  asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
});

$('.slider-nav').slick({
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.slider-for',
  initialSlide: 0,
  dots: false,
  arrows: true,
  infinite: true,
  centerMode: true,
  focusOnSelect: true,
  variableWidth: false,
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.sld-wrp {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slider-for {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

.slide-container {
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  line-height: 40vh;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slide-btn {
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slide-btn:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 179, 0);
}

.slick-current .slide-btn {
  padding: 40px;
}

.slick-list {
  padding: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick-theme.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.js"></script>

<div class="sld-wrp">
  <div class="slider-for">
    <div class="slide-container">go 1</div>
    <div class="slide-container">go 2</div>
    <div class="slide-container">go 3</div>
    <div class="slide-container">go 4</div>
    <div class="slide-container">go 5</div>
    <div class="slide-container">go 6</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="slider-nav">
    <div class="slide-btn">go 1</div>
    <div class="slide-btn">go 2</div>
    <div class="slide-btn">go 3</div>
    <div class="slide-btn">go 4</div>
    <div class="slide-btn">go 5</div>
    <div class="slide-btn">go 6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try to omit the ``slidesToScroll`` property like in the example for the center mode in the [slick documentation](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)?

Comment: @biberman yep, unfortunately it doesn't really help

Comment: Slick seems to center all visible slides and not only the active one. Is it an option to show an uneven number of slides (3 or 5)?

Comment: @biberman not at all. Client requested 4 items in a row 

Comment: @biberman I published similar code on Codepen. May you please check it in your free time and tell me if it's fixable or not? I really can't find any solution during my 4 days of research. Thank you a lot for your help 

https://codepen.io/sergesonkin/pen/OJEpKbP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slick centers all visible items, not only the active one. Therefor it would be enough, to show an uneven amount of slides like 3 or 5.

If that isn't an option, you could use CSS to move the `slick-track` to the left using a negative `margin-left`. The margin amount has to be the half of a slide. Because you want 4 slides, the half of a slide is the 8th part of the track-width, means `12,5%`:

```css
.slider-nav .slick-track {
  margin-left: -12.5%;
}
```

**Working example:**

```js
$('.slider-for').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false,
  // fade: true,
  asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
});

$('.slider-nav').slick({
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.slider-for',
  initialSlide: 0,
  dots: false,
  arrows: true,
  infinite: true,
  centerMode: true,
  focusOnSelect: true,
  variableWidth: false,
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.sld-wrp {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slider-for {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

.slide-container {
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  line-height: 40vh;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slide-btn {
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slide-btn:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 179, 0);
}

.slick-current .slide-btn {
  padding: 40px;
}

.slick-list {
  padding: 0px !important;
}

.slider-nav .slick-track {
  margin-left: -12.5%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick-theme.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.js"></script>

<div class="sld-wrp">
  <div class="slider-for">
    <div class="slide-container">go 1</div>
    <div class="slide-container">go 2</div>
    <div class="slide-container">go 3</div>
    <div class="slide-container">go 4</div>
    <div class="slide-container">go 5</div>
    <div class="slide-container">go 6</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="slider-nav">
    <div class="slide-btn">go 1</div>
    <div class="slide-btn">go 2</div>
    <div class="slide-btn">go 3</div>
    <div class="slide-btn">go 4</div>
    <div class="slide-btn">go 5</div>
    <div class="slide-btn">go 6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```